# English to Language of (PL)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have two sentences that I need to translate from English to the language of predicate logic (which includes a semantics for identity)

1. Ortcutt admires the inventor of bifocals.
2. The first Postmaster General is the inventor of Bifocals.

I know how to symbolize a claim about both existence and uniqueness, i.e., $\exists x (Fx \land \forall y (Fy \rightarrow y=x))$.

However, my first intuitions about how to translate these make the task way too easy, I think. With respect to (1), I just want to let "I" stand for the monadic predicate "is the inventor of bifocals" and put something about Orcutt existing in the admiring relation in there (where "b" denotes Ortcutt...
$\exists x (Abx \land (Ix \land \forall y (Iy \rightarrow y=x)))$

Moreover, translating (2) just intuitively seems to be tantamount to symbolizing, via Russell's Theory, the two definite descriptions and joining them with an = sign.

Does anyone have any tips about how to proceed translating these? Doing so cannot be as simple or straightforward as I think.

Comment: Well, @Rusty, maybe you're really just getting better at this!  Yes, that first translation is absolutely correct, and for the second one you have the right idea as well: please post your suggested formalization of 2.

Comment: Here's what I got for 2:               

$(\exists x (Px \land (\forall y (Iy \rightarrow y=x)) = \exists x (Ix (\forall z (Iz \rightarrow y=z)))$

Comment: No, you cannot put a = between formulas ... you need to put it between objects. In this case, use an $x$ to refer to the first Post master general (for which you should use a different predicate than $I$), and then use a *different* variable (say, $z$) to refer to the inventor of bifocals, and then you can say $x=z$ to say it is the same person. Make sure, thought, that the one statements occurs within the scope of the other, so that both variables are quantified.

Comment: So, given what you've said it sounds like I need to change the variables in front of my existential quantifiers and then add a conjunction at the end where I put each variable on either side of an = sign? 

Alternatively, could I start by saying $\forall x \forall y$ if x is the unique postmaster general and y is the unique inventor of bifocals then x = y?

Comment: The latter strategy of putting both quantifiers at the start will work, but note that you will want to use two existentials. And by the way, I just noticed tou had defined Ix as 'x is *the* inventor of bifocals', but you should use Ix for 'x is an inventor of bifocals', and use the construction that you have been using to make sure that there is one and only one such inventor. Same for the postmaster general

Comment: So, something like $\forall x \forall y ((\exists x (Ix \land (\forall y (Iy \rightarrow y=x) \land \exists x (Px \land (\forall y (Py \rightarrow y=x)) \rightarrow x = y)$?

Comment: Not quite .. note how the $x$ and the $y$ at the start of the statement now have nothing to do with the $x$'s that represent the inventor and postmaster on the inside ... so you really don;t want to use that universal x and y at the start. Rather, do $\exists x \exists z ( \text{'x is the inventor and z the first postmaster'} \land x = z)$

Comment: But if I used $\exists x \exists z$ in the beginning, won't I not just wind up saying that $Ix \land \forall y...$? I guess my question is this: if I put my existential quantifiers out front, I should not be putting any others inside their scope in order to give the Russell analysis of the definite description "the inventor", right?

Comment: You actually *have to* put the $\forall y (...)$ construction inside the scope of both of them (you need two such constructions; one for each of them of course), since that is how you express that there is exactly one of each.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry--I meant to say that I should not be putting any other EXISTENTIAL quantifiers in there.

Comment: Yes, that's right .. just those constructions to 'uniquefy' the $x$ and the $z$

Comment: So here's what I now have: $\exists x \exists y (\forall y (Iy \rightarrow y=x) \land (\forall x (Px \rightarrow x=y) \land x = y).$

Comment: I also got something like this for #3:

$\forall x ((\forall y (x\neq y \rightarrow Lxy) \rightarrow \exists z ((z \neq w \rightarrow Lzw) \rightarrow Lxz)))$